# Android Maps: Failed to load map. Could not contact Google servers

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

This bug has been persistent for forever. (I made sure that "Google Maps Android API v2" is the one turned on.)

Here's the MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.maptest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity { 

    @Override     
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }     
}
```

Manifest:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

     <permission
        android:name="com.example.maptest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.maptest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.maptest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAoDwhSzOopQ3g8NBe7d0WblR72TkmnVPU" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <fragment 
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help! I'm not sure what went wrong...though I did end up following/combining various tutorials because none of them worked on their own.

Comment: 1. Are your signing keys and package name properly registered for that API key?
2. How long did you give it?  API keys are not always immediately effective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1.** The first problem I see is here:

```
<fragment 
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

remove this line:
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

and set `android:name` as:

```
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

**2.** Remove this line from the manifest file:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

This is Google Maps `API V1` permission and shouldn't be use in `API V2`.

Take a look at this blog post and make sure are doing everything correctly:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

**3.** The problem you describing usually derives from a problem in generating or registering the API key using the API Console, If you are positive that you have made all the steps correctly then I suggest you to delete the **debug.keystore** folder, compile some project in Eclipse (this will result in a new SHA1 key) and register the key again using the console. Take a look at this blog post I wrote and make sure I are doing all the steps right:

[Google Map API V2 Key](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

Comment: Hi Emil Adz, i have followed those steps and created a map sample app successfully. and its working on most of the devices(i tested on Galaxy Ace plus, Galaxy 7inch tab and sony xperia Z). but when i try to test the same on HTC Desire its showing error like "Could not find class 'maps.i.k', referenced from method maps.z.ag.a
Failed to load map.  Could not contact Google servers". i have cross verified in that device Google play services are installed. So could you please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Raj, please open a new question and I will try to help you there. Never write a comment with your question.

Comment: Thanks Emil Adz, now its working for me after update maps app in the device. any way thanks for the support.

Comment: I'm glad you figured this out. given the fact that you application worked on all devices except this one, really brings up a flag that there is something in the device configuration and not your application.

Comment: if somebody still looking for an answer, check here - the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17947755/1891118