# Google Maps not showing up Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I receive this error in the LogCat when i try to use the Google Maps API: "Failed to load map. error contacting google servers. this is probably an authentication issue."

I searched all the solutions on the internet, but none of them worked. The api worked until i switched to release api key from debug api key.

I swithed on Google Maps Android API v2 on the API's console, everything... i cleaned the project, delete it and import it again.. etc.. but none of them worked.
Does anyone know what can i do ?

Comment: have you created the new API key and combined it with your package ? that is what usually the authentication issues about the API key

Comment: In google api console recreate the project last week i had the same problem like you now i cleared the problem.

Comment: @Saksak I don't know what you mean. Can you explain it please ?

Comment: @Aravinth Unfortunatly it didn't work.:( Same error..

Comment: @Sebyddd check this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start you might have already checked it, but double check creating the SHA finger print

Comment: I read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667935/failed-to-load-map-error-contacting-google-servers-this-is-probably-an-authent/17947755#17947755 , but i don't know how to "CLEAR DATA".. i tried everything.. @Saksak, i've tried that several times.. nothing.. just the gray space with "+" and "-" buttons..

Answer (score 0):

If you're completely sure that your API key from the manifest file is the right one, your SHA1 key / package name are correctly copied down and you have an active Internet connection, then you should try uninstalling app from your device or emulator and build it again afterwards.