# What's wrong with google map API v2?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, google-maps-api-2

This issue is common BUT I didn't find a solution on google, or stackoverflow (4days of research...)

**Here is the thing :**

I need to display a full screen google map, which i ve already done several times in other application i've developped.
BUT here i can't get it to work for an unknow reason !

The warning and the error i get when i open the SherlockFragmentActivity which contains the map :

```
The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

---

```
Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

**Here i'll explain how i did things in detail and post some code :**

LIBRARY IMPORT :

Last version of Google play services imported in eclipse as library (checked)
In the project the google play services are imported as library in properties (like ABS)

MANIFEST :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pck name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.company.pckgname.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- LOCATION -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name="app variable name"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Styleapp" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="api key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityLauncher"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

... activities...

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

MAP LAYOUT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.company.pckgname.TransparentSupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

ACTIVITY :

```
public class ActivityGoogleMap extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements OnInfoWindowClickListener {

        GoogleMap                   _googleMap;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // ABS
        ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setTitle(R.string.tle_map);
        bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        // MAP
        _googleMap = ((TransparentSupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById((R.id.map))).getMap();

 //the map should still display at this point
        }
    }
```

And so that's it, the main code is here

The map was working up until now, i didn't do nything with the code map related...

I tried to regenerate a debug key on the google console, change the permissions .. etc i am out of idea !!!!

Comment: reboot ur device.and run it again.

Comment: i tryed it many times, even re-install the application, clean the project .. etc

Comment: I'm only guessing, but could your app maybe need internet access permissions?  I've also read that you need to completely re-install the application if you make any permission changes.  Not sure if it's correct but I'm just giving you out some alternative options.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/17668076/2398886

Comment: Read the post the internet permission is there, i'm successfully getting json steam  in the application. No internet issu

Comment: Yes, didn't see it.  Beg your pardon.

Comment: @Tarsem i already got through this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the API key in `AndroidManifest.xml` you **must** clear application data.

To clear application data do one of the following:

- Go to `Settings > Application Manager > Select Your Application > Clear Data`
- Uninstall the application before re-installing it.

Comment: Already done it, as i said i re-installed the application many times

Comment: @Yume117 before `re-installing` did you completely `un-installed` the application ? as on `re-installing application` which is already `installed` its data is not completely cleared !

Comment: That did not resolved my issue but the idea was good ! (it began working again, I have no idea how)

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="131072" android:required="true" />
```

Put this under your permissions in your manifest.

Comment: You forgot the "this"

Comment: it was there sorry i redid it.

Comment: Just tried it, it's the same, i don't think that changing the hexa in integer can change something.

Comment: k when i got google map working there was a google maps v2 and a google maps v2 android do you have the right one checked? no offense but that got me for like 2 weeks

Comment: No offense i've already done the error too ;) but only one time. I don't do this one anymore

Comment: Did that get it Because it would make me feel better about googling nothing for 2 weeks