# Google Maps not shown in android

Tags: android, google-maps

i am using Google maps in my sample android project but it just displays titles nothing else no maps are been display ,i have followed lynda tutorials , Map key is also generated using google map emulator and tested on real deceive as well  still they does not work . Here is the code below .please help

Layout file

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="MyMApKey" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Map Activity :

```
package com.example.maptest;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {
      LocationListener listener ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MapView view = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        view.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        final MapController control = view.getController();
        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
          listener = new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                control.setCenter(new GeoPoint((int)location.getLatitude(), (int)location.getLongitude()));
                manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0,listener);

            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.maptest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.maptest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is output[image]

Comment: Try http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/ and http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Comment: also try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667935/failed-to-load-map-error-contacting-google-servers-this-is-probably-an-authent/17947755#17947755

Answer (score 1):

Note: Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API has been officially deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012. This means that from March 18th, 2013 you will no longer be able to request an API key for this version. No new features will be added to Google Maps Android API v1. However, apps using v1 will continue to work on devices. Existing and new developers are encouraged to use

go to this link google map api v2
step by step description is given. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key

Answer (score 0):

There is no Api Key defined in your android manifest. Your map wont load without that. Second, you didn't define all the permissions in your android manifest. OpenGl, that's also a must.
Refer to this code. This will help you..:)
My Main Activity:

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
Button btn1;
EditText et1;
EditText et2;

GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (servicesOK()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.testmap);

    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);

    }

    /*
     * et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1); et2 =
     * (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext2); btn1 =
     * (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     * 
     * btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
     */

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

/*
 * @Override public void onClick(View v) {
 * 
 * Object lat = et1; Object lon = et2;
 * 
 * Uri uri=Uri.parse("geo:"+lat.toString()+","+lon.toString()); Intent i=new
 * Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); startActivity(i); Log.d("The Location:",
 * lat.toString()+lon.toString());
 * 
 * 
 * }
 */
public boolean servicesOK() {

    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

        return true;

    } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {

        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable,
                this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Cant connect!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    return false;
}
```

}

My Layout:

```
xmlns:maps="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And finally the Android Manifest. This is the most important think you will have to consider:

```
package="com.mike.maps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<permission
    android:name="com.mike.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.mike.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" >
</uses-feature>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.mike.maps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.mike.maps.SecondActivity" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Your API KEY goes here" >
    </meta-data>
</application>
```

Comment: Get your API key from API CONSOLE. To do that you have to login with your gmail account and got to the api access tab and then its a very simple step to get your own key.

you can get your SHA1 fingerprint from Eclipse- window/Android/Build

Comment: i have my API key i just hide it from post.

Answer (score 0):

Google map api v1 is officially deprecated, you can not request for new api key to api v1. Only older api keys will work with google map api v1 which is already been created.

So please try to implement Google Map API V2.

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

use your api key of v2.