# After transferring android studio project from PC to Mac my Google map won't show

Tags: google-maps, android-studio

After transferring my android studio project from my PC to my Mac my Google map won't appear on my app. I get this error when trying to run it from my Mac :

"Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers.".

It worked when I ran it from my PC before I transferred to project. Does anyone know what aspects of the project wouldn't get transferred over that would be causing this error?

Comment: You have the problem about `API_KEY` which is obtained from Google API Access ,so `verify your API_KEY` , `certificate fingerprints` and `package name`. For more details, please refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667935/failed-to-load-map-error-contacting-google-servers-this-is-probably-an-authent).

Answer (score 0):

just replac default.keyset file in .android folder with default.keyset from 1st PC