# Authentication failed on the server and getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to get google maps in my chat application (like whatsapp) on click of the location icon. But it shows only a light grey screen along with a google tag at bottom. In logcat i can see two errors 1) Google appid failed with status 10. 2) Authentication failed on the server. My application already has one GCM key. I don't think there is any error in generating the googlemap key because google map  is visible in another application where i followed same step as of my this application.   Please give me some solutions as i am struggling with problem for a week.

Am i required to generate key with some different approach when using both GCM and google maps??
Is this possible that keys are conflicting right now??
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

According to this [issue](http://android.langhoangal.net/index.php/2015/12/02/getgoogleappid-failed-with-status-10/), one reason that you get `error: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10` is that `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'` is missing in the dependency in project-level `build.gradle` and `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` is missing in the app-level `build.gradle`.

Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365369/googleservice-failed-to-initialize) for more information.

For your issue about the Authentication failed on the server, you can see in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667935/failed-to-load-map-error-contacting-google-servers-this-is-probably-an-authent) the solution for that problem.

Google Maps has Android key and GCM needs Server key, so you need to register the android key to integrate maps with your application.

Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/config#overview) on how to configure Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of grey screen or black in my case was acceleration option in manifest :  android:hardwareAccelerated="false" .

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5767